# Kafka - CommitFailedException - No timeout poll(max.poll.interval.ms)

Tags: spring-boot, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, java-11

I have a Spring Kafka application and I'm getting an error when consumer tries to commit offset. Here is my Kafka consumer configuration:

KafkaConsumer:

```
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, Item> consumerFactory() {
        log.info("Configuring Kafka Consumer properties - consumerFactory");
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "cpo-executor-groupid");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new StringDeserializer(),
                new JsonDeserializer<>(Item.class, false));
}
```

KafkaAdmin:

```
@Bean
public KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin() {
    Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
    configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
}

@Bean
public NewTopic processTopic() {
    return TopicBuilder.name(topicName).partitions(2).build();
}
```

I know that this happen if the process take more than max.poll.interval.ms or session.timeout.ms from kafka, but it is not my case. My application take less than 1 second to consume and process the message:

```
Time: 11:00:32.773 Configuring Kafka Consumer properties - consumerFactory
Time: 11:00:39.433  INFO [cpo-executor,,] 55630 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig
Time: 11:00:57.293 ERROR [cpo-executor,,] 55630 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator: 
[Consumer clientId=consumer-cpo-executor-groupid-1, groupId=cpo-executor-groupid] Offset commit failed on partition process-topic-1 at offset 95: 
The coordinator is not aware of this member.
Time: 11:00:57.299 ERROR [cpo-executor,,] 55630 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] c.c.cpoexecutor.config.KafkaErrHandler   : Error in process with Exception org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: 
Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. 
This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. 
You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records. and the records are []
```

What is happening since I didn't change any Kafka configuration and the default value for max.poll.interval.ms is 5 minutes?

**kakfa: 2.13-2.8.0 

spring-kafka: 2.7.6 

spring: 2.4.2**

Comment: There may be other consumer in the same consumer group. my scenario like this, the consumer fetches messages and send commit request via commitAsync. In the middle of the process, other consumer join or leave the group and occurs the group rebalancing.

Comment: How can I prevent this situation? Could you put your solution? @J.Song

Comment: You can use ACL(access control list) on the topics and consumer groups. If you apply ACL feature, only permitted consumer can join the consumer group and read the topics. The ACL is default feature of apache kafka. Refer the official document.

Comment: But in my case I don't want to use users to control who can read or not the topic. I'm testing the process' read from a topic and probably other user is doing the same. At least now I understand the problem, but I don't know how to solve :(.

Comment: I think, you should use the `consumer group` exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the groupId name according to the environment, so I won't have the same groupId on the same kafka.

KafkaConsumer:

```
@Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}")
private String groupId;

@Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset}")
private String offSetReset;

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, Item> consumerFactory() {
   log.info("Configuring Kafka Consumer properties - consumerFactory");
   Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
   props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
   props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, offSetReset);
   props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
```

application-local.yml:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: #####:9092
    consumer:
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      group-id: cpo-executor-groupid-local
```

application-dev.yml:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: #####:9092
    consumer:
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      group-id: cpo-executor-groupid-dev
```

application-prd.yml

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      bootstrap-servers: #####:9092
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      group-id: cpo-executor-groupid-prd
```